# How to easily define relationships of a pivot table where the third column is a foreign key to another table in laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, pivot-table, laravel-5.1

I am new to laravel 5. I have been working on a client app where I have setup a relationship like so:

1. Many to Many relationship between Application and Cart giving me an application_cart table with columns

   - application_id
   - cart_id

Sample Model

```
class Application extends Eloquent
  {
    public function carts()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Cart');
    }

  }

  class Cart extends Eloquent 
  {
        public function applications()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Application');
    }

  }
```

Using the model above, I have been able to display records beautifully in views like below:

```
 @foreach($cart->applications as $application)
    <td>{{ $application->student->last_name }}</td>
    <td>{{ $application->student->first_name }}</td>
 @endforeach
```

Recently, the client has changed specification so that I have the addition of a third column supervisor_id on the pivot 
  resulting to a pivot table structure like so:

application_cart table

- application_id
- cart_id
- supervisor_id (Foreign key to the supervisors table. A Supervisor Model exist already)

The goal is so that I can now be able to display an output like below:

```
 @foreach($cart->applications as $application)
        <td>{{ $application->student->last_name }}</td>
        <td>{{ $application->student->first_name }}</td>
        <td>
            {{ $application->supervisor->user->name }} <!-- Display the "supervisor name" assign to the application (How can I beautifully display the supervisor name)-->
        </td>
   @endforeach
```

How can I easily integrate this new spec in my code?

**Edit**

Sketchy diagram of how the relationship might look like:

[image: Sample Class Diagram]

Answer (score 0):

`Application.php` needs a `supervisor()` relationship

```
public function supervisor() {
    return $this->hasOne(App\Supervisor::class);
}
```

Your `Supervisor.php` model needs a `user()` relationship

```
public function user() {
    return $this->belongsTo(App\User::class);
}
```

For this to work, your `supervisor` table must have a `user_id` column, and your `supervisor` table must have a `application_id` column.

You don't put a third foreign key in a pivot table. Keep application_cart as it is, referencing an application and a cart. While the supervisor foreign key can be defined per application, as I'm assuming you want one supervisor per application.

Comment: Thanks for your input @Pistachio. Actually a supervisor can be assign to different applications but you can't have an application with more than 1 supervisor. Actually I can't have application_id on the supervisor table because supervisor is just a type of user inheriting a parent user.

Comment: Hi @FokwaBest, did you find any solution to this? I'm stuck with similar situation.